# Call a D function from C with string argument

Tags: c, string, char, d

OK, so basically, this is what I'm trying to do...

I have a D function like :

```
extern (C) {
  void someFunc(string s) {
    writeln("Got : " ~ s);
  }
}
```

I want to call this from C code with a `char*` argument.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just found the answer (there was no issue with how it was called, but how I converted the `char *` to a D-compatible `string`) :

```
extern (C) {
  void myfunc(char* s) {
    writeln(to!string(s));
  }
}
```

Comment: Whenever possible, if you have the length of a string or array on the C side (not common with strings but sometimes you do) it is good to pass both the pointer and the length. Then you just slice it on the D side ptr[0 .. length] and you can use that. Be careful with memory management of slices though. The `to!string` solution has the advantage of making a new copy so you know it won't be freed by C.